# IMemoryCache in .NET Core GetOrCreate function is called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using IMemoryCache to speed up my web application. Therefor I cache a whole database table of products with all the linked details in a webshop. The caching function takes up to 20 seconds.

```
private List<Article> Articles {
    get {
        return _cache.GetOrCreate("Articles ", entry =>
        {
            entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            return CacheArticles(); // takes 20 seconds
        });
    }
}
```

One page-request in our webshop uses the `Articles` multiple times and there are always multiple users on our shop. Now we have the problem that the caching method takes up to 20 seconds, within that 20 seconds the `Articles` are called a lot of times and every time the `CacheArticles()` method is called again, because the cache was not filled yet.

How can we avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) to ensure that `CacheArticles` is called only once at a time.

```cs
private readonly object locker = new object();

private List<Article> Articles {
    get {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return _cache.GetOrCreate("Articles ", entry =>
            {
                entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                return CacheArticles(); // takes 20 seconds
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it will block all calling threads while `CacheArticles` runs, this may or may not be a problem for you

Answer (score 0):

This is where `lock` statement comes in.

Define this at you class level as static to being shared for everyone that access that class.

```
private static object __AriticleTableLock = new object();
```

Then where you want to fill your cache use this code:

```
 lock (__AriticleTableLock)
 {
   // your code comes here...
 }
```

This cause this part of code is accessible for only one user.

Note that `__AriticleTableLock` is `static` because it's gonna be shared for all users in your application.

Comment: Please look at [lock docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).